# Running a task post maven install

Tags: maven-2, maven

I want to run a simple exec command post maven install phase. What is the simplest way possible to achieve this? (without adding new plugins)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you want to run this command as part of the normal build lifecycle, there is no other way than binding the `exec` goal on the `install` phase:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>my-exec</id>
          <phase>install</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>exec</goal>
          </goals>
          <inherited>false</inherited>
        </execution>
      </executions>
      <configuration>
        <executable>COMMAND</executable>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

I did a simple test using the configuration above (using `ls` as "COMMAND") with a freshly created maven project and running `mvn install` produces the following output:

```
$ mvn install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building maven-exec-testcase
[INFO]    task-segment: [install]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
...
[INFO] [install:install {execution: default-install}]
[INFO] Installing /home/pascal/Projects/maven-exec-testcase/target/maven-exec-testcase-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to /home/pascal/.m2/repository/com/mycompany/app/maven-exec-testcase/1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-exec-testcase-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] [exec:exec {execution: my-exec}]
[INFO] pom.xml
[INFO] src
[INFO] target
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESSFUL
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 12 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Jan 05 19:26:04 CET 2010
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/75M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

As we can see, the command is executed **at the end** of the `install` phase (after the copy of the artifact to the local repository).

And if you really don't want to add the snippet to your pom, then you'll have to explicitly call `exec:exec` after `install` on the command line as suggested by whaley.

Answer (score 5):

The maven default lifecycle ends with the *install* and *deploy* goals - there is no pre- and post- version of those goals.

Potential options would be to:

- Bind the exec:exec mojo to with the deploy phase.  I would warn you against that idea as the deploy phase is really meant to deploy artifacts to a remote maven repository.
- Run the exec:exec mojo after the install goal in your mvn invocation... e.g.:

  mvn clean install exec:exec -Dexec.executable="yourcommand" -Dexec.args="arguments"
- If you have a multi-module project, create another module at the end of your <modules> and bind exec:exec to any of the usual goals within that module.  This will force this particular module to run last assuming other [criteria the reactor looks at](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html) isn't met.  A common strategy I employ with maven projects I work on is "when in doubt, create another module".