# How to deploy an unmanaged plugin and restart the Neo4j server from maven?

Tags: java, maven, neo4j, graph-databases

I am trying to make my development process as automatic as I can.

I am using maven and got the deploy to work by simply putting the jar in my server folder when building the project (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757426/maven-specify-the-outputdirectory-only-for-packaging-a-jar)).

This works fine, but I still have to restart my server manually. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005165/running-a-task-post-maven-install) solution to run a command after install.

I can run `neo4j` to start the server, but can not find out how I can restart (or stop and then start). I tried `neo4j restart` and got the following output:

> This command is not supported by the Neo4j utility. Please try "Neo4j.bat help" for more info.

When running `Neo4j.bat help` I get the following output:

> Proper arguments for this command are: help console

Something does not seem right... I am using Neo4j version 2.2.0.

This could be a bad approach, if so let me know. How do you setup your environment when developing unmanaged extensions?

Answer (score 4):

You can use chaining of commands

`neo4j stop & neo4j start`

If you run on windows I recommend you to upgrade to latest version of Neo4j, because it supports PowerShell instead of old batch files.

http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/powershell.html

Answer (score 2):

In Neo4j 2.3.0 you have powershell modules that should allow you this kind of functionality.

http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/powershell.html

Comment: How can I run commands in Powershell from maven? I am able to start Neo4j with `Start-Neo4jServer -console` in Powershell.