# Run a script after maven install

Tags: java, bash, shell, maven, maven-3

I have a Maven project and after I install the project I need to run a script. I want to automize this process. My guess is that by adding something in the pom file I could automize this, but so far i haven't found how to run a script after installation. I only found how to run a script before the maven project has finised installing.

So, how can I run a script after a Maven project as finished installing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2008258/4796021

Comment: This version runs the script before maven install. I use maven3.

Comment: This kind of goes against the whole Maven model. If the script you need to run comes after Maven install, it seems likely that it is out of the scope of Maven's responsibility. You are better off writing a wrapper script that executes both maven and your post-install script.

Answer (score 7):

Use the http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/ exec-maven-plugin, in conjunction with an "executions" configuration block that specifies the installation phase. Make sure it is after your maven-install-plugin as plugins are ran in order (within the same phase)

```xml
(in build/plugins)  
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.2</version>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>install</phase>
        <goals>
           <goal>exec</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <executable>do-something.sh</executable>
          <workingDirectory>/some/dir</workingDirectory>
          <arguments>
             <argument>--debug</argument>
             <argument>with_great_effect</argument>
          </arguments>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: Don't include ant configurations just to do stuff there's maven plugins for.  That makes your configuration maintenance include support for both Maven and Ant!

Answer (score 3):

For a purely maven-driven approach, the answer you're looking for is the `exec` goal of `exec-maven-plugin`, and this answer applies: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2008258/3403663

EDIT: OP indicates the above doesn't work for him.

**Alternative approach**: I just tried the following in my own project, and it executes `ls` at the very end of the install phase, after artifacts have been deployed.

`mvn clean install exec:exec -Dexec.executable="/bin/ls" -Dexec.args="/etc"`

Otherwise, you could always just wrap the whole thing in a script:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -o errexit

mvn clean install
<your other commands here>
```

Comment: The solution from the link doesn't work, the script is run before maven install., Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you do something like this? This will go after the normal maven install phase.

EDIT: If you add the maven-install-plugin before it, maven will run each in the order they are in the pom.

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.2</version>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>install</phase>
        <configuration>
          <tasks>
            <exec
              dir="${project.basedir}"
              executable="${project.basedir}/src/main/sh/do-something.sh"
              failonerror="true">
              <arg line="arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4" />
            </exec>
          </tasks>
        </configuration>
        <goals>
          <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Source: [maven-antrun-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-ant.html)

Comment: I trired to put this in the build tag from pom and the script run before maven install finished installing.

Comment: There's an exec plugin, seriously don't chain to ant to have ant chain to exec.

Answer (score -3):

You can chain the commands

```
$ mvn clean install && myscript.sh || echo "error."
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I want a pom configuration, if this is posible.